# Does IPEndpoint have to be up-cast and why?

Tags: .net, sockets, f#, dns

```
let test_smtp (smtp_server_address : string) (port : int) =
    let hostEntry : IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(smtp_server_address)
    let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (hostEntry.AddressList[0], port)
    ( use tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) 
      tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint)
    )
```

In the incomplete code snippet above,

`let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (hostEntry.AddressList[0], port)`

generates two errors. The first indicates an appropriate overload method cannot be found.

The second error, which I have not seen before, is

`This value is not a function and cannot be applied.`

I isolated this to the `hostEntry.AddressList[0]` by having a separate let statement that assigned to an IPAddress, and the error mapped to that line (not included in the sample above).

I have seen some articles about F# not being able to up-cast, but I am still a little bit confused as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: You need to use `.[0]` to index into a collection - otherwise it's parsed as applying a function to the list `[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kvb said in a comment

```
a[0]
```

means "treat `a` as a function applied to the single argument 'list containing just zero'".

You want

```
a.[0]
```

to get the zero-index element of array `a`.

Once you fix that, type inference will work for overload resolution and not need the cast, etc.